# Is there a way to change the format on how Yii2 creates ID's for fields within ActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using ActiveForm with Yii2 and by default it seems to generate default **id's** for fields if you don't set one, in the format of:

```
{action-name}-{field-name}
```

So for example if I had a field with the `name` of `foo_bar` used in an action of `actionSettings` then the id of this field would be generated as:

```
settings-foo_bar
```

I would prefer this to just be `foo_bar`.

Is this possible to change on a form by form basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveField `id` is by default created based on the form's model name and field's name.

If you want to change it for the whole form override [the method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.11.2/framework/widgets/ActiveField.php#L846) that does it:

```
protected function getInputId()
{
    return $this->_inputId ?: Html::getInputId($this->model, $this->attribute);
}
```

and use this modified class in your form.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43285513/472501) provided by @Bizley I was investigating how the method calculated the name and found out there is another way to achieve this as well.

You can simply override the `formName` method of your respective model to return a blank value, such as:

```
public function formName() {
    return '';
}
```

Whilst this has less overheads as you don't need to create a new class, it will also affect other things within your form such as the field *names* and also should **not** be used for forms which contain multiple different models as explained [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName()-detail).

Lastly, because this question was about changing how Yii *formats the id*, @Bizleys answer is the correct one; my solution is just another option of *possibly* achieving it another way.